# Getting cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method. on kotlin dagger2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

```
error: app.sareing.core.sharedPrefs.StringPreference cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
public abstract void inject(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                     ^
  app.sareing.core.sharedPrefs.StringPreference is injected at
      app.sareing.activity.MainActivity.authToken
  app.sareing.activity.MainActivity is injected at
      app.sareing.injection.component.ActivityComponent.inject(activity)
```

Tried Named fields, still no luck solving this.

Comment: Show your module and app.sareing.core.sharedPrefs.StringPreference classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48057282/9821453

I was not using @fields:qualifier_name while injecting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Dagger, you have two way to provide an object

1. Using @Inject in the construction

Example:

> UserRepository @Inject constructor(private val mContext: Context)

2. But how can we @Inject constructor with some class of the third party like Retrofit Service Interface? That why Dagger has @Provide

Example:

`@Module class AppModule {
@Provides
    fun provideContext(application: Application): Context = application.applicationContext }`

Dagger also has some other way to provide an object

You can read more [here](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide)

In your case, you can provide your StringPreference class in your app module like AppModule

`@Module
class AppModule {
 @Provides
    fun provideStringPreference(context: Context): StringPreference = StringPreference(context)
}`